# How to get back to type-ahead search in Nautilus?

Tags: fedora, gnome, nautilus

Is there a way to use type-ahead search rather than "filtering" in newer Nautilus versions (I use 3.14 on Fedora 21)?

E.g., when I type in "worl" in a directory with files named `Hello` and `World`, `Hello` just gets filtered out - while what I want is to move current selection to `World`, without any filtering in a current directory. The latter behavior can be seen in Ubuntu's version of Nautilus, while on Fedora there's no such a setting in Options window or in dconf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Fedora 21: Typeahead search in Nautilus possible?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59284/fedora-21-typeahead-search-in-nautilus-possible/) :

> The type-ahead search is not supported in GNOME. It works in Ubuntu,
>   because Ubuntu developers [created a patch](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-14-04-nautilus-type-ahead-patch) to re-enable this
>   behavior but it has [never been accepted by GNOME developers](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=721968).
>
> Might be easier to just install nemo and use that.